# How to get parent folder name using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

How to get parent folder name from worspacefolder path in nodejs.I tried but not working.can anyone find where i did the mistake? prevFolder name should be rain.

```
  var pathname=vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri;  
  /* c:/xampp/htdocs/rain/tree */

  var prevFolder= path.dirname(pathname).split(path.sep).pop();

  console.log(prevFolder)
```

Comment: Let me check. 1 min

Comment: No..not working..getting like this:  /c:/xampp/htdocs/

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood.  This is all you need `path.basename(path.dirname(pathname))`  No need for array manipulations.

Comment: You are asking to point out your error. You got answers referring to the code you showed. That code is essential for your question. It seems that you accidentally deleted it. I hence undid that edit. Please keep in mind, that questions need to make sense even after having received answers. Especially they need to keep those answers valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own solution will work if you don't use path.sep (since you are on Windows, it is set to '\' and not '/':

```
var prevFolder= path.dirname(pathname).split('/').pop();
```

But to avoid the separator issue completely, you could use:

```
var prevFolder= path.basename(path.dirname(pathname));
```

Probably more efficient than the split method, too.

Comment: Can you post your answer for that question?

Comment: Wow, your edit looks pretty similar to my earlier answer... Thanks.

Comment: @Mark, didn't see your answer when editing mine. They are actually identical. A strong sign that this might be the right way to do it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
var prevFolder = path.basename(path.dirname(pathname));
```

No need for array fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current working directory from `process.cwd()`; After that, you can use it up to your choice.

Comment: If we use process we can not get workspace folder path

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the command "vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri".
But if it returns "c:/xampp/htdocs/projects/rain/tree" and you need tree, you can do:

```
  var pathname=vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri
  var prevFolder= pathname.split("/");
  console.log(prevFolder[prevFolder.length-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
path.dirname(filename).split(path.sep).pop()
```